# How to insert a HTML tag around the first letter of a specific tag with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, hover, pseudo-element

I can't figure this one out. Is there a way to insert a HTML tag around the first letter of a specific tag with JQuery?

e.g. I have this:

`<h1>Heading</h1>`

but I need this:

`<h1><span>H</span>eading</h1>`

I want to create a CSS animation on the first letter of a tag when I hover over it.

The `h1:hover:first-letter` CSS doesn't seem at all supported. Targeting it with the `<span>` seems my best option. Sadly inserting the `<span>` directly into the HTML is not an option.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 5):

```
var t = $('h1').text();
$('h1').html('<span>'+t.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+t.substring(1));
```

**EDIT:** per your comment, break the code into a function and apply it to each element (I also made the function more dynamic so you can wrap the first character in anything you want).

```
$('#main-nav li').each(function() {
    wrap_first_character(this, $('<span>'));
});

function wrap_first_character(ele, tag) {
    var t = $(ele).text();
    $(ele).append(tag.html(t.substring(0,1))).append(t.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! For this project I need to target a group of tags e.g.`#main-nav li` When I use this code on more than one tag I get some strange behaviour, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm not getting the result I'm after. Am I doing anything wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/nA8Gw/

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it the other way around, by wrapping your `<h1>` with another element (to hover over), then using CSS to target the first letter of the `<h1>` itself. This way you avoid string manipulation, and replacing the whole content of your header:

JS

```
$('h1').wrap('<div>');​
```

CSS

```
div:hover h1:first-letter { color: red; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPYgX/

Comment: Nice! I didn't think about targeting it with the CSS like that. It works very nicely. Thanks.